# Navigation to google.com and search a string in an aspx page and show the whole process to the user in the browser

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, silverlight, browser

Is it possible to navigation to any website like google.com using Webbrowser or any other .net technology like silverlight, html5 etc. in a webpage and programmatically enter in textbox "stackoverflow" and then click search button and then get the results back to save in the database. But most importantly show the whole process of navigation and textbox filling and button click and results to the user in the browser window and webpage.

It can be easily done by putting a webbrowser control in a windows form in windows .net assembly so that user also sees it. But I was wondering if this can be done in a web based way. User must be able to see everything in the browser page in the same way it happens in a windows form with the webbrowser control.

I want to develop a web-based software that does web automation and also show it to the users as it is happening without user downloading any exe etc. Just web based.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it can be done to some extend. But to show the entire process to the user, its another issue. How do you want to share the screen ?

there are a lot of 'browser automation' tools like watin or selinium, where you can 'make' the browser execute actions which are pre-defined.

Again where do you want to 'execute' these all ? In clients browser or on server ? If you do in server, you can share the screen via some streaming API's to the client via flash or silverlight.

Comment: I want to develop a web-based software that does web automation and also show it to the users as it is happening without user downloading any exe etc. Just web based.